# C++ use temp variable or class variables when saving state of variable affected by user input

Tags: c++, file, class, variables, class-variables

I have a class with variables, together with getters and setters. I am creating a user registration system. The user first has to create a profile for themselves by entering details such as name and age etc. This data should be retrieved later for them to edit or view during the operation of the system. I am unsure if it better OO design to user temp variables for the first object serialisation when no record of the person exists or use the setters on the class variables which are later pushed to the file? i.e. push class variables or temp variables. Also, when using MVC, I think it easier to use class vars as it easier to separate the view from the controller functions i.e. saving to file function. However, it is expensive to initialise the vars then clear. Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt on reading the question:
use temp variables to let the user enter information, then make an object with the given information and let the object do the validation.  If the information is valid, add to the user container and do the serialization.

This way, you have a central place for validation and only one way for serialization.

However, as far as I know, there is no one solution that fits everything.